# Rails 4 Controller: How to use logical operators properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, controller, logic

I have a location model and inside my locations controller I am searching for near locations using the geokit gem:

```
@locations = Location.near(current_user.location, 250)
```

How can I actually distinguish in a controller action like that whether a Location is `is_remote == true` or not?
Meaning:
`@locations` should actually output all the locations, which are either `is_remote == true` **or** `near(current_user.location, 250)`.

Thanks in advance for each answer! Please tell me if you need additional information.

Comment: How can you get the Locations with the 'is_remote == true' condition?

Comment: `Location.where(is_remote: true)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add them together:

```
@locations = Location.near(current_user.location, 250) + Location.where(is_remote: true)
```

Just in case some are duplicates you can `uniq` them:

```
@locations = (Location.near(current_user.location, 250) + Location.where(is_remote: true)).uniq
```

Or you can even use the Ruby [set union operator](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Array.html#method-i-7C) instead of `+` and `uniq` (although some might argue it's not as readable):

```
@locations = Location.near(current_user.location, 250) | Location.where(is_remote: true)
```

Comment: Hmm... that relly should work but for me it does not somehow... I check in my View if `@locations.exists?`. As soon as I do what you suggested I get a No Method `undefined method 'exists?'` I also secured that each part works fine with itself so there has to be an issue with your suggested solution.

Comment: `exists?` is an `ActiveRecord::Relation` method, by adding or unioning the two Location scopes it turns `@locations` into a plain Array. With this solution you need to use Array or Enumerable methods like `@locations.any?` or `@locations.size != 0`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! :)